# Как правильно: "опека" или "опёка"?

Tags: фонетика

Долгие годы у нас вместо буквы "ё" писали "е". Это перешло и в нашу речь. Как правильно: опека или опёка?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же, *опЕка*, от слова *пЕчься*(заботиться). А как же обстоят дела с самими буквами Ё и Е?
*На самом деле*: Согласно правилам русского правописания, употребление буквы ё в большинстве случаев факультативно (т. е. необязательно).
*Азбучная истина*. Употребление буквы ё обязательно в текстах с последовательно поставленными знаками ударения, в книгах для детей младшего возраста (в том числе учебниках для школьников младших классов), в учебниках для иностранцев. В обычных печатных текстах ё рекомендуется писать в тех случаях, когда возможно неправильное прочтение слова, когда надо указать правильное произношение редкого слова или предупредить речевую ошибку. Букву ё следует также писать в собственных именах. В остальных случаях употребление ё факультативно, т. е. необязательно.
А более полный ответ - [Написание е вместо ё – грубая орфографическая ошибка.](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/).

Answer (score 3):

Меня тоже заинтересовало, почему печь-пеку-пёк, а опека- не Ё. Посмотрела его этимологию, оказалось, что опека-заимствование,только по смыслу связанное с русским печься:
Происходит от польск. орiеkа — то же, чешск. рéčе «забота», польск. орiеkun «опекун», орiеkоwас́ się «заботиться»; ср.: русск.опеку́н, опека́ть, укр. опíка. Вероятно, калька лат. prōcūrātor. Эти слова связаны с др.-русск. пекуся «забочусь», ст.-слав. пекѫ сѩ, пешти . Ср. пеку́, печа́ль.
Поэтому е не перешло в о, как в исконно русском печь от пекти (приготовлять пищу.Праславянское pekti-пекти -это застывший дат. пад. сущ. печь (действие и предмет). Выходит, так тоже бывает: русское слово по значению совпало с заимствованием.

Comment: Тем не менее, слова связаны и происхождением. "Калька с латинского" как раз и предполагает использовние "родного" корня. В данном случае - общеславянского.

Comment: почему же использование?Просто параллельно шли два процесса: в русском от глаг.пекти-сущ.пека (зной, жар - пекло)в диалектах совпало со значением печаль(праслав.)-пека-забота(беспечный, опекать)
А в 18 веке в официальных документах появилось заимствование со  значением "надзор за недееспособными". Удивительно, что оно осталось,  слилось с русским , но  изменения русской фонетики на него не подействовало.Видимо, чтобы сохранить стилистические отличия: опека-забота и опека-надзор.В русском Ё возможно: он пёкся о его здоровье-е перешло в о(ё ).Опека - нет.

Answer (score 2):

"Опека" дейсвительно заимствование. Но вообще-то вопрос надо бы ставить не откуда Е в опеке, а откуда Ё в слове пёк. По логике Ё там быть не должно. Сравните: пекарь. 
И я не могу точно сказать, почему там оно появилось.

Comment: Это как раз просто.Печься-пёкся- не историческое чередование, а современное словообразовательное:  |о – е| – при мотивации глаголами печь (пёк) и течь (тёк),  в отдельных образованиях при мотивации глаголами грести (грёб), цвести (цвёл); в случаях кочевать и корчевать  (кочёвка, корчёванный ).Но это говорит о том, что это русское словообразование, а вот опека именно заимствование, от него только форма опекать, а пёкся о ком-то - совсем  другой глагол, в другом  значении.

Comment: >Печься-пёкся- не историческое чередование, а современное 
     
Это-то понятно. Иначе и вопроса бы моего не было.  

>Но это говорит о том, что это русское  
   
Ни о чем это не говорит. Е переходит в Ё всегда между мягким и твердым согласным за исключением случаев, связанных  с историческим ятем и шипящими. Ну и нескольким исключениями. В числе которых как раз печь. Была бы описываемая мотивация - получился бы именно пёкарь.